# JProfiler - Unable to profile remote jboss through tunneling

Tags: java, jboss, remote-server, jprofiler, tunneling

Am not able to profile my remote server . This remote server has to be connected through a global server , so i have to use tunnel for connecting to my server . Whenever am connecting to my remote server , jprofiler is showing the following message

> Another application is listening on port 12345 . Please check your
>   port configuration

Initially i was able to connect to this jboss for profiling through the same configurarion , Can some body figure me out what can be the reason for above case?

Answer (score 0):

"Another application is listening" means that JProfiler opened a socket connection, but the magic number of the JProfiler protocol was not sent by the remote side. For example, this would happen if the remote port served HTTP pages.

Comment: So how can i solve this problem , am profiling a jboss application . Am able to connect to the remote application only once , after that if i want to connect again it is showing the above message

Comment: You can connect multiple times to a profiled process. It must be a problem with the tunnel.