# How to use JProfiler over two-hop SSH tunnel

Tags: java, remote-server, tunnel, jprofiler, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to connect JProfiler to a JVM running on a server that I'll call **remote**. This server is only accessible from my workstation (**local**) via another server that I'll call **middle**. My plan for connecting JProfiler to **remote** was this:

1. Install the JProfiler instrumentation on **remote**
2. Establish SSH tunnel from **local**, through **middle**, to **remote**:

   `ssh -v -N -L 8849:[remote's private address (192.168... etc)]:8849 [middle]`
3. Establish a new JProfiler session on `localhost:8849`, choosing *"Startup immediately, connect later with JProfiler GUI"*

However, I end up getting an error:

> **Connection error**
>
> Either an old version of the native library is used or another
> application is listening on port 8849. Please check your
> DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable and your port configuration

I don't have any other programs bound to local port 8849, aside from my SSH tunnel, and I have confirmed that the SSH tunnel itself should be working correctly - I'm able to forward connections for a test HTTP server from **remote** to **local** via a similarly configured tunnel.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101112/jprofiler-unable-to-profile-remote-jboss-through-tunneling) similar question, but no solution was provided.

What am I missing from my configuration?

Answer (score 1):

A **direct tunnel** is established with

```
ssh -t user@remote -L [localPort]:localhost:[remotePort] -N
```

A **2-hop tunnel** is built with chained ssh commands:

```
ssh -t user@middle -L [localPort]:localhost:[remotePort] \
ssh -t user@remote -L [remotePort]:localhost:[remotePort] -N
```

where `localPort` is the port you want to use locally, and `remotePort` is the port that the profiling agent is listening on. All of this is executed in a single command on your local machine. More hops can be added with additional ssh calls like in the first line. There must by exactly one trailing `-N` for the entire command.

This approach works with JProfiler.

If the tunnels fails or if the profiling agent is not listening, you will get the message that you mentioned because of the way that the connection fails in the case of an SSH tunnel.