# JProfiler, connecting to a machine behind a firewall

Tags: java, ssh, jprofiler

I am trying to use JProfiler on my MAC to connect to a machine remotely that is behind a firewall and only accessible via a Linux machine.

I have set up a direct SSH tunnel as follows:

```
ssh -L 8849:remote:8849 forwardingmachine
```

And start Jprofiler with

```
java -agentpath:/path/jprofiler8/bin/linux-x64/libjprofilerti.so=port=8849 ..."
```

I systematically get the error:

> Connection error
>
> Either an old version of the native library is used or another
>   application is listening on port 8849. Please check your
>   DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable and your port configuration

Online there are solutions for using a 2 hop SSH tunnel, but I can't do that due to the second machine only being accessible to forwardingmachine.

Any ideas of how to get around this?

(The remote machine uses Java 1.7, whereas my Mac uses Java 1.8). Both machines are using jprofiler8

Answer (score -1):

A direct tunnel to `remote` is set up with the command

```
ssh -t user@remote -L [localPort]:localhost:[remotePort] -N
```

Comment: I am setting up a connection via "forwardingmachine, from remote:8849 to local:8849 as remote:8849 is behind a firewall. I don't believe your answer is correct.

Comment: So the 2-hop solution should be applicable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27138011/how-to-use-jprofiler-over-two-hop-ssh-tunnel in your case.

Comment: The 2 hop approach requires you to have a direct connection to remote, which I don't

Comment: The idea of the 2-hop connection is that you don't have a direct connection to remote, the connection to remote is initiated on middle, not on localhost